# Api links not working

Tags: php, json, api

sorry if this is going to be kind of vague. I bought a script and it was supposed to be automated. The site uses an api to get the information and place it on my site. What is happening is if a user clicks on an album it goes to a link something like this:

```
mywebsite.com/album/-458/beatles/
```

> The page doesn't work

but if I manually take out the hyphen by going to to the link and deleting the hyphen and pressing enter - it works like this:

```
mywebsite.com/album/458/beatles
```

Anything that can point me in the right direction. I would post code but I really don't even know where the problem is occurring. Please be kind :)

Comment: From the question you asked and the amount of details you provided, I can only reply with... don't add the hyphen in. Provide code for other to try detect if its your code appending the extra character or the APIs fault. It's really hard to determine anything from the information you've presented.

Comment: I don't know where the hyphen is coming from. If I knew, I could fix it. I don't where in the code it would be.

Comment: Post the source code of the page that displays all the album links